# Fragment recreated after popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments: A, B, C.

If I go A -> B and press back. Fragment B just disappears and you see fragment A exactly like it was before transaction.

If I go A -> C and press back (in exactly same manner) - fragment A is recreated! (calling onAttachFragment, onCreate, onCreateView etc). No "onDetach called ever".

I can't find out what the difference and why is that happens.

I use ".add" only (no replaces, no removes).

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_enter_left, R.anim.slide_exit_left, R.anim.slide_enter_right, R.anim.slide_exit_right)
            .add(R.id.fragment_holder, newFrag)
            .addToBackStack(backName).commit();
```

How to prevent recreating of fragment A? It should be under B and just reappear when B goes out?
Any ideas?

Comment: for prevent recreating of fragment , use replace method instead of add, so fragment will not store in stack.

Comment: Replace will do remove (and add).  So this will force recreating when go back.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution.

It has nothing to do with fragments at all.

Posting here for sake of someone faces same problem.

I was creating fragment A in activity's onCreateOptionsMenu.

That called every time there is a change in appbar's menu.

Fragment C not dealed with menus, so onCreateOptionsMenu was not called when entering/exiting this fragment, but fragment B added button on appbar, so called activity's onCreateOptionsMenu and that recrated the A fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use null in addToBackStack(null) method of your fragment transaction

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_enter_left, R.anim.slide_exit_left, R.anim.slide_enter_right, R.anim.slide_exit_right)
            .add(R.id.fragment_holder, newFrag)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: This will NOT store the A fragment in stack and surely need to recreate it. So it's opposite of what I need.